# How to save character output in loop?

Tags: r

So I made this function, that only takes one numerical element, not a vector.

```
salaryCategory=function(s){
  if(s>=40000 && s<70000)
    print("Low")
  if(s>=70000 && s<100000)
    print("Medium")
  if(s>=100000 && s<140000)
    print("High")
  if(s<40000 || s>=140000)
    print("Invalid")
}
```

Now Im trying to save output using this function inside of a vector.

My goal is to use a loop and use this function to make a another vector with output from the function.

When I try to run this.

```
k=c(500000,75000,100000,42000)
j=c()
for (i  in 1:length(k)) {
  
  
  j[i]=salaryCategory(k[i])
  
  
}
```

The output Im going for is to save the out put from the function inside "j"
so what I want it to look like is this.

```
j=("invalid","Medium","High","Low")
```

Its not saving the code inside of j and I dont know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use **return** in your function instead of print

```
salaryCategory=function(s){
  if(s>=40000 && s<70000)
    return("Low")
  if(s>=70000 && s<100000)
    return("Medium")
  if(s>=100000 && s<140000)
    return("High")
  if(s<40000 || s>=140000)
    return("Invalid")
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, I appreciate it. The answer was sitting in front of my face and I didnt realize it.

Comment: It happens  :) Given your problem is solved, it would be great if you accept one of the answers that you align closest with.

Comment: Thank you! And you used the question formatting quite well despite being new to the community. Kudos!

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, for if/else/... statement, format is like

```
if (condition) {
  action
}
```

And to give an input, `print` is not appropriate.

Therefore, your function should be

```
salaryCategory=function(s){
  if(s>=40000 && s<70000){
    ("Low")
  } else if
  (s>=70000 && s<100000) {
    ("Medium")
  } else if (s>=100000 && s<140000) {
    ("High")
  } else if (s<40000 || s>=140000) {
    ("Invalid")
  }
    
}
```

And for `j`,

```
j=c()
for (i  in 1:length(k)) {
  j <- c(j, salaryCategory(k[i]))
}
j

[1] "Invalid" "Medium"  "High"    "Low"
```

Your way for `j` works too.

```
j=c()
for (i  in 1:length(k)) {
  
  
  j[i]=salaryCategory(k[i])
  
  
}
j

[1] "Invalid" "Medium"  "High"    "Low"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `cut()` function and avoid the nested if statements.

```
 #test data
 s<-c(0, 50000, 80000, 110000, 200000)

 cut(s, breaks=c(-Inf, 40000, 70000, 100000, 140000, Inf),
       labels=c("invalid", "Low", "Medium", "High", "invalid") )
```

Answer (score 0):

your code in function `salaryCategory` has response output value without save the value,  you must change output to return value in function `salaryCategory` with code

```
salaryCategory <- function(x) {
if(s>=40000 && s<70000)
    return ("Low")
  if(s>=70000 && s<100000)
    return ("Medium")
  if(s>=100000 && s<140000)
    return ("High")
  if(s<40000 || s>=140000)
    return ("Invalid")
}
```